# Perl reverse array function not working correctly as intended

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm trying to reverse an array using reverse function but the output of array is same as input i.e my intended output is 0,1,1 but the output I'm getting is 1,1,0...I'm using online compiler for the code.

```
@arr=qw(1,1,0);
@rev=reverse @arr;
print @rev;
```

Comment: How many elements does your array have?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!!! It would have caught your error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the comma in `qw` elements. [More details about quote operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

```
@arr = qw(1 1 0);

print @arr;
print "\n";
@rev=reverse @arr;
print @rev;
```